# Ошибка компилятора в Python, код на чат-бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, отладка

Прошу помочь в редактировании кода. Вот сам **код:**

```
def bot(while i!="выход":
    i=input('Привет!')
    if i=='привет':
        print('Как дела?')
    elif i=='хорошо':
        print('У меня тоже.')
    else:
        print('Я вас не понял'))
bot()
```

Компилятор выводит ошибку:

```
 def bot(while i!="выход":       
                ^                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

P.S.Если что-то не дописал (не хватает информации) пишите в комментариях.
Это бот 'говорилка' или чат-бот, пользователь вводит что-либо а бот отвечает заготовленные фразы.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, что должен делать код.

Comment: Кто-либо вводит либо "привет" и бот выводит "Как дела?" и т.д.

Comment: А вы принципиально не берете строковые данные в кавычки ---  input(Привет!), print(Как дела?)

Comment: Нет. Cпасибо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может все таки стоит придерживаться синтаксиса Python?

```
def bot():
    i=""
    while i!="выход":
        i=input("Привет!")
        if i=='привет':
            print("Как дела?")
        elif i=='хорошо':
            print('У меня тоже.')
        else:
            print('Я вас не понял')
bot()
```

Диалог:

```
Привет!привет
Как дела?

Привет! плохо
Я вас не понял

Привет!привет
Как дела?

Привет!хорошо
У меня тоже.

Привет!выход
Я вас не понял
```

Comment: Не, неработает... :-(

Comment: Что именно не работает?  Работает в точности так, как вы написали. А если вы хотите написать что-то другое, то скажите, что именно должна делать ваша программа.

Comment: Я скопировал ваш код, и конретно в точности он и не работает.

Comment: А вы попробуйте еще раз. Подозреваю, что что-то вы скопировали "не так". На всякий случай - я для вас подправил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
import webbrowser

def bot():
    i = ""
    while i != "выход":
        i = input('Введи приветствие: ')
        if i == 'привет':
            print('\nКак дела?\n')
            i2 = input('Введи, как у тебя дела: ')
            if i2 == 'хорошо':
                print('\nУ меня тоже.')
                break
            else:
                webbrowser.open('https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy')
                break

        else:
            print('Я вас не понял\n')
```

Comment: А зачем \n?....

Comment: @Egr Красиво же)

Comment: И всё?.........

Comment: Я художник, я так вижу. Мне нравится черезстрочный интервал в терминале. На самом деле это перенос строки, чтобы в терминале всё лучше смотрелось

Answer (score 0):

```
i=''
def bot():
  global i
  i=input('>')
  while (i!='vihod'):
    <условия>
    i=input("Что?)")

bot()
```

Comment: Ну, я её в конце закрыл. А что так нельзя?

Comment: Ну, со строками все понятно. А синтаксис языка Python вы  учили?